# WCF discovery: EndpointNotFoundException even though the endpoint was found

Tags: .net, wcf, ws-discovery, wcf-discovery

I'm using WS Discovery to dynamically find and connect to endpoints on the local network.

```
var cli = new DiscoveryClient (new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint ());
var response = cli.Find (new FindCriteria (typeof (IFoo)));
```

returns `net.tcp://localhost:8000/`, which is correct. But

```
var ep = new DynamicEndpoint (
    ContractDescription.GetContract (typeof (IFoo)), new NetTcpBinding ());
var cf = new ChannelFactory<IFoo> (ep);
var ch = cf.CreateChannel ();
ch.SomeMethod ();
```

throws an EndpointNotFoundException with this message:

> "1 endpoint(s) were discovered, but the client could not create or open the channel with any of the discovered endpoints."

I googled for the error message but there were no results! What is happening, and how can I fix this?

Comment: I already found an answer, which I'll post in a second. This question was added just for reference, since it was difficult to google for this error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in my case the error was due to a wrong binding - its SecurityMode was not set correctly.

Comment: Please give me the information about what you did with your Security mode settings